# why isn't createViewModel binding custom component correctly?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've tried building a simple custom knockout component as part of a test I'm trying to do. Unfortunately I seem to be having some issues with the data-binding that look similar to [Set viewModel = $data for Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546961/set-viewmodel-data-for-component) however the resolution there doesn't seem to have fixed my case.

I've created a small example below, where I'm trying to use this custom component. This fails with the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return bookNum }"
>   Message: bookNum is not defined

This issue seems to be around the context binding, if I were to change the HTML binding to include `$parent` then it would work, however obviously this shouldn't really be required:

```
<p data-bind="text: $parent.title"></p>
```

Here's a snapshot of the context debugged in the browser:

[image]

```js
ko.components.register("myCustom", {
 viewModel: {
  createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
   var context = ko.contextFor(componentInfo.element);
   var self = context.$data;

   // Add a computed value on
   ko.utils.extend(self, {
    bookNum: ko.computed(function() {
     switch(self.title()) {
      case "A": return 1;
      case "B": return 2;
      case "C": return 3;
     }

     return -1;
    })
   });
  }
 },
 template: '<div class="book">\
                  <div data-bind="text: bookNum"></div>\
                  <div>:</div>\
                  <div data-bind="text: title"></div>\
                  <br/>\
               </div>'
});

var vm = {};
vm.items = ko.observableArray();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function() {
 vm.items.push({ title: ko.observable("A") });
 vm.items.push({ title: ko.observable("B") });
 vm.items.push({ title: ko.observable("C") });
}, 1500);
```

```css
.book div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <p data-bind="text: title"></p>
  <div data-bind="component: { name: 'myCustom' }"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Skeeves I'm not sure why you deleted your answer, but you were actually correct. You may want to add it back (maybe with a little more explanation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the ko.utils.extend function.

Comment: Thanks - I simplified the case in my question (I'm actually loading the JS and HTML for the component from remote files) and forgot that this was going into a `createViewModel` function - at which point the missing `return` statement becomes much more obvious.